# Reference to non-static member function must be called

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

I'm using C++ (not C++11). I need to make a pointer to a function inside a class. I try to do following:

```
void MyClass::buttonClickedEvent( int buttonId ) {
    // I need to have an access to all members of MyClass's class
}

void MyClass::setEvent() {

    void ( *func ) ( int ); 
    func = buttonClickedEvent; // <-- Reference to non static member function must be called

}

setEvent();
```

But there's an error: "Reference to non static member function must be called". What should I do to make a pointer to a member of MyClass?

Comment: You can't have a function pointer assigned to a member function. You either have to use a pointer to member, or a free function.

Comment: What do you mean by the "pointer to a member"? As for "free function" you meant a function outside a class? Yeah, I know that it will work if I'll remove "MyClass::" part from definition "void MyClass::buttonClickedEvent..." but I need to have an access to members of MyClass inside the function "buttonClickedEvent"...

Answer (score 69, accepted):

The problem is that `buttonClickedEvent` is a member function and you need a pointer to member in order to invoke it.

Try this:

```
void (MyClass::*func)(int);
func = &MyClass::buttonClickedEvent;
```

And then when you invoke it, you need an object of type `MyClass` to do so, for example `this`:

```
(this->*func)(<argument>);
```

http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/cpp/article.php/c17401/C-Tutorial-PointertoMember-Function.htm

Comment: By the way, when I call this->*func(23) - it doesn't work because I need to use it with parentheses like this: (this->*func)(23)

Answer (score 19):

You may want to have a look at https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/pointers-to-members#fnptr-vs-memfnptr-types, especially *[33.1] Is the type of "pointer-to-member-function" different from "pointer-to-function"?*

Answer (score 0):

you only need to add parentheses after the function call and pass arguments if needed

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).