# How to call stl::nth_element with a member function inside this class?

Tags: c++, stl, pointer-to-member, nth-element

I want to use the function `nth_element` with my own sorting function (which should have access to the data of the object) within a class. Currently, I am doing the following:

```
class Foo
{
 public:
   glm::vec3 *points;
   int nmbPoints;

   bool idxPointCompareX(int a, int b);
   void bar();
}

bool Foo::idxPointCompareX(int a, int b)
{return points[a].x < points[b].x;)

void Foo::bar()
{
   stl::vector<int> idxPointList;
   for(int i = 0; i < nmbPoints; i++) idxPointList.push_back(i);  

   stl::nth_element(idxPointList.first(),idxPointList.first()+nmbPoints/2,idxPointList.end(), idxPointCompareX);
}
```

Of course, this did not work and I got the error: "reference to non-static member function must be called". After that, I had a look at [Reference to non-static member function must be called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26331628/reference-to-non-static-member-function-must-be-called), [How to initialize `std::function` with a member-function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23962019/how-to-initialize-stdfunction-with-a-member-function) and some other questions on here. I understand why this did not work, but I'm unsure how to solve this.

Can someone help me and tell me how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To take the address of a member function you need to use the correct syntax, i.e. `&Foo::idxPointCompareX` not just `idxPointCompareX`

But you also need a `Foo` object to call the function on, so you would need to bind one to it. Presumably you mean to call it on `this` so you could use `std::bind`:

```
using namespace std::placeholders;
stl::nth_element(begin, begin+n, end,
                 std::bind(&Foo::idxPointCompareX, this, _1, _2));
```

Or simpler, use a lambda function:

```
stl::nth_element(begin, begin+n, end, 
                 [this](int a, int b) { return idxPointCompareX(a, b);}
);
```

This creates a lambda function that captures `this` and passes its arguments on to the idxPointCompareX function on the captured `this` pointer.

Comment: As I mentioned already under his answer, I made a mistake while writing the question. idxPointCompareX uses an index to get access to the point data of 'points'.

Comment: you're missing n'th element here. `stl::nth_element(begin, begin + smth, end, 
                 [this](int a, int b) { return idxPointCompareX(a, b);}
);`

Answer (score 2):

`idxPointCompareX` is a member function, i.e. it cannot be called without some reference to a `Foo` object. Looking at its definition though, it seems that it doesn't need to be a member since it's purely defined in terms of its arguments.

You could make it a `static` function (i.e. a "class function") or a free function and then pass that to `std::nth_element`.

Comment: I am sorry I made a mistake in the question. I will edit it directly after posting this.

Answer (score 0):

You can't call an object method before it is created, so you have some options here:

1. Make the method static
2. Leave the constructor empty and move all into an `init` method where you call the compare part
3. Use a lambda

#### Examples:

Static method:

```
static bool idxPointCompareX(glm::vec3 a, glm::vec3 b)
{return a.x < b.x;)
```

Init method:

```
Foo::bar()
{
   stl::vector<int> idxPointList;
   for (int i = 0; i < nmbPoints; i++)
       idxPointList.push_back(i);  
}

Foo::init()
{
    stl::nth_element(idxPointList.first(),
                     idxPointList.first()+nmbPoints/2,idxPointList.end(),
                     idxPointCompareX);
}
```

Lambda:

```
Foo::bar()
{
   stl::vector<int> idxPointList;
   for (int i = 0; i < nmbPoints; i++)
       idxPointList.push_back(i);  

   stl::nth_element(idxPointList.first(),
                    idxPointList.first()+nmbPoints/2,idxPointList.end(),
                    [](int a, int b){return points[a].x < points[b].x;));
}
```

I would go for the lambda version myself.