# Functor -> reference to non-static member function must be called

Tags: c++, function, class, functor

I have a class whose member function I am trying to point to, problem is I keep getting this error `reference to non-static member function must be called` which from my understanding is that a member function needs to be pointed to. The problem is, when I try to use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26331779/3491653) solution, the compiler complains because `there is no viable conversion from 'void (Foo::*) (const List&) to std::function<void (const List &)>`

This is my `Foo` class:

```
class Foo {
public:
  int Run( int port);
  void HandleRequest(HTTPServerRequest* request);

private:
    int num_ports;
    void callback_method(const List& );

};  //class Foo

void Foo::HandleRequest(HTTPServerRequest* request){
std::function<void (const List&)> functor = callback_method;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can do like this:

```
void Foo::HandleRequest(HTTPServerRequest* request){
    std::function<void (const List&)> functor =
        std::bind(&Foo::callback_method, this, std::placeholders::_1);
}
```

or:

```
void Foo::HandleRequest(HTTPServerRequest* request){
    std::function<void (const List&)> functor = 
        [this](const List& list){callback_method(list);};
}
```

Comment: thank you! works like a charm. I used the first option. Can you please explain it to me?

Comment: you can see this:[link](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind)