# "Reference to non-static member function must be called" on class method

Tags: c++

I'm learning c++ and have faced a weird error (see title). Inside class instance I'm trying to call another function from that class while adding it to a vector of threads. This is my sample code:

file: `header.h`

```
class MyClass{
    void threaded_func();
    bool main_func();
};
```

file: `main.cpp`

```
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
#include "header.h"

using namespace std;

vector<thread> threads;

void MyClass::threaded_func()
{
    cout << "I'm threaded_func\n";
}

bool MyClass::main_func()
{
    vector<thread> threads;
    threads.push_back(thread(threaded_func));

    return true;
}

int main()
{
    MyClass mc;
    return 0;
}
```

This returns me an error `reference to non-static member function must be called`. I've checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26331628/reference-to-non-static-member-function-must-be-called) question, however it didn't help me (replacing `thread(threaded_func)` with `thread(MyClass::*threaded_func)`). I also tried to use `this` keyword to tell compilator I'm using the same class member to invoke method, but seems that my C++ knowledge is simply too low to solve this problem.

Are there any workarounds? I've also looked through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/670734/c-pointer-to-class-data-member) question, however it is about variables, not functions.

Comment: If the goal is to create a thread that run `threaded_func` on the current object, then the thread has to have two arguments: the function to call, and the argument. `thread(&MyClass::threaded_func, this)`. But if you're struggling with fundamental syntax issues you probably shouldn't be writing multi-threaded code yet.

Comment: @PeteBecker I'm making a pool of threads which are doing _something_. Could you please point me to these "fundamental syntax issues" which I don't see here?

Comment: The fundamental syntax issue here is that you're trying to pass a member function by giving its unqualified name. I showed you the correct syntax.

Comment: @PeteBecker edit: Sorry, you're right. Thanks (edited this comment since I had a bug)